# ValidationError doesn't get printed in my web

Tags: python, django, validationerror

I've been learning django for two weeks now and I'm currently learning raising forms.Errors such as forms.ValidationError.
Here's the code I've written:

```
def clean_email(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if not email.endswith("gmail.com"):
          raise forms.ValidationError("This is not a valid email")
        return email
```

The problem I have is when I write an email that doesn't contain gmail.com, ValidationError doesn't get printed in the web.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this to your templates

```
{{ form.email.errors }
```

and maybe try to change this line in your models

```
raise forms.ValidationError({'email': ["This is not a valid email"]})
```